# Mysterious missing dependency in AWS Lambda docker image

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, sentence-transformers

I have been struggling on this for a few days. I have been following this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html

**What do I try to accomplish?**

I want to have a lambda function in AWS to convert text into vectors in order to put those in a vector database.
To do this, I would like to use all-MiniLM-L6-v2 model from sentence-transformers.
(if there is an easier way, I'm all ears)
Note: I can't define this lib as a layer in AWS as this lib is too big.

**What do I want?**

I want to install sentence-transformers in the /tmp folder as this seems to be the only writable folder in AWS Lambda.
I need this as otherwise, I get errors because the package tries to write within the packages folder, even after defining the TRANSFORMERS_CACHE env variable.

**Why am I stuck?**

When I test this locally, it works well, running docker run -p 9000:8080 image:tag
But once deployed, I get the following error:

> Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'sentence_transformers'

The right folder /tmp/packages is in the path as print(sys.path) gives:

> ['/var/task', '/var/runtime', '/var/task', '/tmp/packages', '/var/lang/lib/python311.zip', '/var/lang/lib/python3.11', '/var/lang/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages']

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

# get the dependencies, sentence-transformers for instance
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# The actual lambda function
COPY lambda_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
    
# Install the specified packages, target should be /tmp as it is the only writable directory
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target=/tmp/packages

# Add the new packages folder to the PYTHONPATH so it can be imported in the script
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/tmp/packages"

# set the handler function as the starting point for the lambda function
CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]
```

**lambda_function.py**

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
import os
# important to change the cache folder to a writable folder (only the tmp folder is writable on AWS Lambda)
# this must be before import SentenceTransformer
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE'] = '/tmp/cache/huggingface/models'
os.environ['HF_DATASETS_CACHE'] = '/tmp/cache/huggingface/datasets'
os.environ['HF_HOME'] = '/tmp/cache/huggingface/home'
import json
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')


def handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "res"
    }
```

**requirements.txt**

```
sentence-transformers
```

What am I missing?

Edit: When I list folders in /tmp/packages, locally, I get all the expected dependencies, but on AWS, the folder does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

When I list folders in `/tmp/packages`, locally, I get all the expected dependencies, but on AWS, the folder does not exist.
I'm not 100 % sure why but it might be about the tmp folder being reset at each run or something like this. (TBC)

So I had to back-pedal.
The issue is that it was missing one env variable `XDG_CACHE_HOME` leading to errors about read only folders etc.

So here is what worked:

lambda_function.py

```
import os
# important to change the cache folder to a writable folder (only the tmp folder is writable on AWS Lambda)
# this must be before import SentenceTransformer
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE'] = '/tmp/cache/huggingface/models'
os.environ['HF_DATASETS_CACHE'] = '/tmp/cache/huggingface/datasets'
os.environ['HF_HOME'] = '/tmp/cache/huggingface/home'
os.environ['XDG_CACHE_HOME'] = '/tmp/cache/huggingface/xdghome'
import json
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
```

Here, you need to define all those environment variables.

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

# get the dependencies, sentence-transformers for instance
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# The actual lambda function
COPY lambda_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the specified packages, target should be /tmp as it is the only writable directory
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# set the handler function as the starting point for the lambda function
CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]
```

Normal Dockerfile, installing the packages in the default location.